# How to make a Python FMX GUI Form jump to the front?

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, window, firemonkey

I have a window `Form` that is created with the [DelphiFMX GUI library for Python](https://github.com/Embarcadero/DelphiFMX4Python).

I want to know if there is a specific method that I can call to send the Form to the top above all other forms and/or windows from other apps.

Here's my current code. I want to make sure the `NewForm` is sent to the top when the button is clicked via the `Button_OnClick` method:

```
from delphifmx import *

class HelloForm(Form):
    def __init__(self, owner):
        self.Caption = 'Hello World'
        self.Width = 1000
        self.Height = 500
        self.Position = "ScreenCenter"

        self.myButton = Button(self)
        self.myButton.Parent = self
        self.myButton.Text = "Bring other form to front"
        self.myButton.Align = "Client"
        self.myButton.Margins.Top = 20
        self.myButton.Margins.Right = 20
        self.myButton.Margins.Bottom = 20
        self.myButton.Margins.Left = 20
        self.myButton.StyledSettings = ""
        self.myButton.TextSettings.Font.Size = 50
        self.myButton.onClick = self.Button_OnClick

        self.NewForm = Form(self)
        self.NewForm.Width = 1000
        self.NewForm.Height = 500
        self.NewForm.Show()

    def Button_OnClick(self, sender):
        # What code do I write here to send to front?

def main():
    Application.Initialize()
    Application.Title = "Hello World"
    Application.MainForm = HelloForm(Application)
    Application.MainForm.Show()
    Application.Run()
    Application.MainForm.Destroy()

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the built-in `BringToFront()` method on every `Form`. You can add the following code to your `Button_OnClick` function:

```
self.BringToFront()
```

So your whole function would look like this:

```
def Button_OnClick(self, sender):
    self.BringToFront() # Bring the form to front
```

Just for some added information. If you want a Form to be permanently on top of every other window or app, then you can set the `FormStyle` property when you create the form:

```
self.NewForm.FormStyle = "StayOnTop"
```